# Login twitter using Request

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, text-mining

I tried to login into twitter using Request, whenever i scrape the authenticity token it comes back as a None so i can't **extract value** for it.

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    from requests import Session
    with Session() as s:
      user= s.get("https://twitter.com/login?lang=en")
      bs_content =soup(site.content, "html.parser")
      token3 = bs_content.find("input", {"name":"authenticity_token"})["value"]
      token4 = bs_content.find("input", {"name":"wfa"})["value"]
      token5 = bs_content.find("input", {"name":"ui_metrics"})["value"]
      user_data= {"session[username_or_email]": "*********","session[password]": "*********","redirect_after_login":"/explore","remember_me":"1","authenticity_token":token3,"wfa":token4,"ui_metrics":token5}
      s.post("https://twitter.com/login?lang=en",user_data)
      home= s.get("https://twitter.com/explore")
      print(home.content)
```

It returns the error below:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-23-4c38afe6cb36> in <module>()
      5   user= s.get("https://twitter.com/login?lang=en")
      6   bs_content =soup(site.content, "html.parser")
    ----> 7   token3 = bs_content.find("input", {"name":"authenticity_token"})["value"]
      8   token4 = bs_content.find("input", {"name":"wfa"})["value"]
      9   token5 = bs_content.find("input", {"name":"ui_metrics"})["value"]

    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Your bs_content is `None`. Most likely because your `site.content` is also `None`

Comment: this is my question to . if found solution message me